# npm install failing - angular cli

Tags: npm, angular-cli, npm-install

Lately the npm install has been failing with the following message in console. Have no idea what the issue is.

**Error**:

```
2018-05-28T14:47:28.3230547Z ; HOME = C:\Users\buildguest2018-05-28T14:47:28.3230759Z ; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
2018-05-28T14:47:28.3230939Z 
2018-05-28T14:47:28.3372485Z [command]C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd install --PackagePath=D:\a\1\a
2018-05-28T14:47:48.4771492Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:49.2608559Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:49.2615800Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:49.2727576Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:49.3246328Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:50.0623974Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:51.0242068Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:51.0884552Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:51.1812943Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:51.7897654Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:52.4974313Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:52.7069867Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:52.9240502Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:53.4517970Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:53.7299054Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:53.9328990Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:54.8136674Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:54.9153675Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:55.3377875Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:55.3378230Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:56.7503115Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:57.4878844Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:57.4879250Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:57.4879498Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:57.4925519Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:47:57.5087845Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:48:00.4542911Z (node:3856) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2018-05-28T14:50:28.3702606Z npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/define-property/-/define-property-2.0.2.tgz
2018-05-28T14:50:28.3708350Z npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.18.94.96:443
2018-05-28T14:50:28.3829528Z npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/nanomatch/-/nanomatch-1.2.9.tgz
2018-05-28T14:50:28.3829792Z npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.18.94.96:443
2018-05-28T14:50:28.3931251Z npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/arr-diff/-/arr-diff-4.0.0.tgz
2018-05-28T14:50:28.3931610Z npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.18.94.96:443
2018-05-28T14:50:28.3931993Z npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/extglob/-/extglob-2.0.4.tgz
2018-05-28T14:50:28.3932200Z npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.18.94.96:443
2018-05-28T14:50:28.4020591Z npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/array-unique/-/array-unique-0.3.2.tgz
2018-05-28T14:50:28.4020862Z npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.18.94.96:443
2018-05-28T14:50:28.4034130Z npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/fragment-cache/-/fragment-cache-0.2.1.tgz
2018-05-28T14:50:28.4034584Z npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.18.94.96:443
2018-05-28T14:50:28.4122832Z npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/snapdragon/-/snapdragon-0.8.2.tgz
2018-05-28T14:50:28.4123225Z npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.18.94.96:443
2018-05-28T14:50:28.4133235Z npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/to-regex/-/to-regex-3.0.2.tgz
2018-05-28T14:50:28.4133454Z npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.18.94.96:443
2018-05-28T14:50:28.4134052Z npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/object.pick/-/object.pick-1.3.0.tgz
```

**Steps**:

```
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 8080",
    "build": "rimraf dist && ng build --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "a": "ng serve --aot --port 8080"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "7.2.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.1.0",
    "@types/jquery-jcrop": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "jquery-jcrop": "^0.9.13",
    "jsnlog": "2.23.0",
    "ng2-translate": "5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "signalr": "^2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.41",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.26.13",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.46",
    "@types/materialize-css": "0.98.2",
    "@types/mcustomscrollbar": "2.8.31",
    "@types/node": "6.0.78",
    "@types/swiper": "2.0.34",
    "@types/underscore": "1.8.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/jquery-jcrop": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/xlsx": "0.0.36",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.3",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "jquery": "2.2.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin": "3.1.5",
    "materialize": "1.0.0",
    "materialize-css": "0.97.6",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.3",
    "swiper": "3.4.2",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.6",
    "tslint": "5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "jquery-jcrop": "^0.9.13",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

uninstall node and install it again from the website https://nodejs.org/en/download/